# Hadoop Shuffle Questions

Tags: hadoop, shuffle

I have just learned the book <**Hadoop:The definite Guide**>.I have several questions on the most important process:**Shuffle**.

1. The time order of ***sort***,***partition*** and ***merge***

   The output of a mapper maybe the input of several Reducers.From the book ,we know that the mapper will write its output to its memory buffer firstly.And before it spills the buffer to disk , a sort and partition is conducted.I want to know their order in time.My inference is:Before the result is spilled to dist, a partitioned is conducted to determine which reducers the output belongs to.And then ,for each partition ,a sort method(as I know ,it is quick sort) is conducted seperated. When the buffered is full or reached the threshold, then a spilled to disk.
2. each ***spill file*** and ***merged file*** belongs to each reducer or multi-reducers?

   Again ,according to the book ,when there are too many spilled file, a merge operation will occur.It confused me again.

   2.1 Does each spill file belongs to each reducer, or they are just a simple dump file of memory buffer and belongs to multi-reducers?

   2.2.After the spill files are merged, the merged file will contain the input data for several reducers? Then when it comes to the copy phase of reducer,how can reducer get the part which actually belongs to it from this merged file?

   2.3 Each Mapper Task will generate a merge file, instead of each taskTracker,right?